# Very interesting problem with integral,number theory and irrationality

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, pi, trigonometric-integrals

It's a problem that I found interesting because it gives an approximation of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and a sequence of term .I can add to my problem a bit of elementary number theory furthermore.Finally and maybe we can make a link with the irrationality of $\pi$

We have that :

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\sin(x)-1)^n}{(\sin(x)+1)^n}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{a}{b}$$
Where $n\geq 2$ a natural number and $a,b$ natural number to find.

### Remark (number theory)

> > 1)$b$ is always dividing by $5$
> >
> > 2)$a$ is always a composite number .

### Remark (irrationality)

When $n$ increasing the integrals tends to $0$ so the fraction tends to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.Unfortunatly $a,b$ are choose arbitrary so it's  inconvenient if we want to prove the irrationality of $\pi$ and caluclate the integral is delicate.

### Remark sequence

[$n=2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive%20%28sin%28x%29-1%29%5E2%2F%28sin%28x%29%2B1%29%5E2%20at%200%20to%20%28pi%2F2%29) 
[$n=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive%20%28sin%28x%29-1%29%5E3%2F%28sin%28x%29%2B1%29%5E3%20at%200%20to%20%28pi%2F2%29)
[$n=4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive%20%28sin%28x%29-1%29%5E4%2F%28sin%28x%29%2B1%29%5E4%20at%200%20to%20%28pi%2F2%29)
[$n=5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive%20%28sin%28x%29-1%29%5E5%2F%28sin%28x%29%2B1%29%5E5%20at%200%20to%20%28pi%2F2%29)

### My questions :

Can someone prove these remarks ?

Is the sequence referenced and is there a recurrence formula?

Can we prove the irrationality of $\pi$ with the integral ?

Thanks in advance !

### Last remark :

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\sin(x)-1)^{n-1}}{(\sin(x)+1)^n}dx=\pm\frac{1}{2n-1}$$

So integration by parts is your friends in this case .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{\sin x-1}{\sin x+1}\right)^n dx
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{\cos x-1}{\cos x+1}\right)^n dx
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(-\tan^2\frac x2\right)^n dx\\
&=2\int_0^{1}\frac{(-t^2)^n}{1+t^2} dt
=2\int_0^{1}\left(\frac1{1+t^2}-\frac{1-(-t^2)^n}{1+t^2}\right) dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}2-2\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kt^{2k} dt
=\frac{\pi}2-2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $$\frac ab=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}.$$

The fact that the limit of the above sum for $n\to\infty$ is equal to $\frac\pi4$ is very well-known and as far as I know never was used for a proof of the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you evaluate the initial integral with another way ?

Comment: I would assume that it is - as usual - possible to evaluate the integral in many ways, but what do you hope to obtain from an alternative derivation of the same result?

Comment: Oh nothing just for the fun Is this proof of the Leibniz formula well-know ?

Comment: The proof of Leibniz formula follows from $$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=[\arctan t]_0^1=\frac\pi4$$ which was used in my derivation. :)

Comment: Thanks !You solved my problem .

Comment: You're welcome!